# Meaning of “potentially not”

Tags: meaning, phrases

I was speaking to my brother earlier today about Stephen Graham’s new film Boiling Point having watched it last night with a friend. Before giving my opinion on the film, I asked “Are you going to see it?”. He replied “Potentially not”. Twenty minutes  later and we were still arguing on what ‘potentially not’ means.

To me ‘potentially not’ indicates that something is currently going to happen but in the future circumstances or opinion might change that makes it not happen. In this example, it would indicate that yes he is going to the see the film but he might not as something might happen that stops him. More specifically the position would be something like “yes I’ve got a ticket to go with Tom but my boss did say earlier I might have to work on Friday night”, I.e. “yes but potentially not”.

My brother argued all ‘potentially not’ means is no different than ‘potentially yes’. He thinks that ‘potentially not’ means that he’s currently 50/50 or undecided but would err on the side that he will not see the film. I told him this makes no sense but he was adamant that’s what it means. His position seems to me to be more “maybe but probably not” rather than “potentially not”.

I have heard people say “potentially”, “potentially yes” and “potentially no” in response to questions, as well as all the        ”probably’s” as well.

Any thoughts on what “potentially not” means. I tried looking the phrase up but I couldn’t see much about it. Is it a misuse of the word potentially?

Comment: IMO it would mean that he intends to, but might not, for example if you tell him a spoiler, or give a poor opinion – something that puts him off watching it. What the chance of that happening isn't relevant. OTOH if he replied "Potentially, yes" I would take that to mean he has not planned to, but could be open to persuasion.

Comment: I'm fairly the phrase is deliberately intended to be unclear.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit the question to show that you've looked up a dictionary definition of *potentially*. I think you're working with a personal definition that isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Related: [What the "primarily opinion-based" close reason is for](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/) ('"Primarily opinion-based" is designed to stop "What's the best X?"-type questions. It's not supposed to be used on every single question that involves opinions').

Answer (score 2):

> “Are you going to see it?”. He replied “Potentially not”.

=The answer to your question has the potential to be in the negative.

Whereas this is literally noncommittal as there is an equal potential of its being in the positive, the answer contains a hint, via the very mention of “not”, that he will not be seeing it.

At this point, your decision is between accepting that he will not see it and not mention the film again, and selling the picture to him so as to move the potentiality of his seeing it into the positive.

> Twenty minutes later and we were still arguing on what ‘potentially not’ means.

I assume that the entertainment value was worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of *potentially* includes the meaning of *possibly*, but goes beyond it. A seed is potentially a plant; that means not only that it is possible that the seed will develop into a plant, but that there is something in the seed **now** that **tends** towards its growing into a fully developed plant. An art instructor may say of a young student that she has a potential to become a great artist; that would mean not only that she might become one, but that she is displaying some talents now that tend towards artistic accomplishments in the future.

So saying that one will potentially see a film  would imply that one is now developing some curiosity about the film that tends towards motivating one to see it. Saying that one will potentially **not** see a film, on the other hand, would imply that one is now developing some doubts about the film that tend towards demotivating one from seeing it. While one can imagine quite a few circumstances in which the former would be apt, it is is not so easy to imagine the circumstances in which the latter would be apt. This is because not seeing a film is the default. Against the background of that default, it will usually be informative to say that one is developing some curiosity to see the film, but not that one is developing a tendency not to see it. For the latter to be apt, one would need to suppose some relatively unusual circumstances that affect what the default is (e.g. one always goes to see every new film of that director, but the reviews of this film indicate that it may not be worth seeing).

Answer (score -1):

I think “potentially not” just sounds bad all-around, personally. If I was there, my argument would be that he should never use it again. However, I’d probably lean more towards your brothers argument that “potentially not” is, more or less, the same as “potentially yes”.

Definition of potentially via Merriam:

> in a potential or possible state or condition —used to describe the possible results or effects of something

The key word here being *possible*.

If he were to just say “potentially” in response to your question, it is implied that what he’s really saying is BOTH “potentially yes” AND “potentially no”. Again, I don’t like the phrase all-around, but if he’s including the “no” because he’s leaning more towards the side of not seeing the movie, then I’m okay with it.